# dstore QueryMethods.js 404

Tags: dojo, http-status-code-404, dstore

I'm trying to instantiate a Request dstore. When requiring dstore, it seems to be looking for `dstore/src/QueryMethods.js` which does not exist. A `dstore/src/QueryMethod.ts` (typescript) file DOES exist, but not JS.

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid", "dgrid/Keyboard", "dgrid/Selection", "dstore/SimpleQuery", "dstore/Request",  "dojo/domReady!"]...
```

returns .../dojo/src/QueryMethod.js Status=404.

I must be missing something here!

Thanks,
Noah

Comment: Should read 'looking for `dstore/QueryMethod.js`' not 'Methods'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.

You have the wrong version of dstore.
Check the README.md file.
It states the version with Typescript is for Dojo 2.
It also points to previous versions.

I grabbed:
https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/tree/1.1

And now the error is gone and everything works.